# Gradle project sync failed. During the 1st run

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to install Android Studios for the 1st time i see this following error while gradle sync.

Android version: ICS

PC: Windows

This is my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

**ERROR**

> Error:(1, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments
>   [build_5pnbu8h0dy4utgbvgbaqkp5m1$_run_closure1@1219d79f] on project
>   ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Post your top level build.gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/build.gradle` file you have to add the android plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { ... }
```

Comment: getting an error **files under the build folder generated and should not be edited** in Gradle sync 12error and 2 warning

Comment: You have to edit the app/build.gradle not the files in the build folder